# FlexeLint/PC-lint is warning about that return value of std::string::append is not considered

Tags: c++, stdstring, pc-lint

[FlexeLint/PC-lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/products.htm) is warning about that the return value of std::string::append is not considered on following reduced [sample code](https://ideone.com/g10zSg):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

std::string s("Hell");
s.append(1,'o');

std::cout << s << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Calling FlexeLint gives the following warning:

```
Warning 534: Ignoring return value of function  'std::basic_string<char>::append(unsigned long, char)'
```

While that message is true, it does not make sense to catch the return value in this case because [std::string::append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) simply returns *this.

In addition, any iterators, pointers and references related to this object may be invalidated. But this not the case, no iterators, pointers and references are used.

**Question**

Did i miss something important or is this simply a false positive of FlexeLint?

Comment: *While that message is true* -- Well isn't that the job of a lint utility, and that is to find any and all issues (unless you suppress those warnings)?  I wouldn't want to have a utility that decides on its own what it wanted to show me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I still think the tool should me more clever, even on really simple cases like this. My understanding of a linter tool differs from yours - I would want to have a utility that is intelligent enough to decide whats relevant.

Comment: @orbitcowboy intelligelt analysis is a continuum and I can assure you that FlexeLint already filters away a lot of stupid false positives. It is non-trivial to get compete with skilled and motivated human analysis :)

Answer (score 1):

PC-Lint is quite flexible and most of the time it's possible to tweak it to your needs. There are several ways to disable this warning:

- Using the global option `-e534` (covers all functions)
- Using the global option `-esym(534,std::basic_string<char>::append(unsigned long, char))`
- Adding the comment `//lint !e534` on the same line

Comment: Thank you for this. I still think the checking of PC-Lint can be improved in this case, because it simply does not make sense to catch the return value here. Instead of suppressing errors, the tool should be improved!

Comment: Another way to disable the warning is to write (void)s.append(1,'o'); This solution does not clutter the code with lint comments and no external suppression list has to be maintained.

Comment: I couldn't get the explicit -esym suppression to work, but this did instead: `-esym(534,std::basic_string*::append)`